# For a text file that has some number of lines for a particular category, how do I append those in-between lines to a list?

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like:

```
[START]
hey there
how are you
[END]
[START]
i am great
long time no see
[END]
[START]
yeah
busy lives
[END]
```

If I want to append all the lines in between the dividers [START] and [END] to a list, how would I do it?

I tried doing this:

```
f = open(filename)
f.readline()
lst = []
while not (line == '[START]'):
    lst.append(line)
return lst
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = open("file.txt")
line = f.readline()
lst = []
while line:
    if not ('[START]' in line or '[END]' in line):
        lst.append(line)
    line = f.readline()
return lst
```

you can replace /n or [START] or [END] with line.replace("/n","")

Answer (score 0):

This can be done rather simply with a list comprehension:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    return [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file if line.startswith('[START]') or line.startswith('[END]')]
```